# Can 8-bit (bits per sample) PCM WAV files contain more than one channel?

Tags: c++, audio, wav, riff

I realized it is bad for me to neglect this thought, because I haven't read anything about `number of channels` and `bits per sample` in this light. My reason is that I'm not sure how the samples of 2-channel 8-bit PCM files will look like.

Is it `1 sample = 1 channel`? or `1 sample = 4 bits (left) + 4 bits (right)`

Context:
I am writing a program that reads WAV files, and it occurred to me that if I come across 8-bit PCM WAV files, and my code reads this way (see below), then my program is unable to properly read multi-channel 8-bit PCM WAV files.

---

```
// read actual audio data after obtaining
// the headers
// audioData is a vector of vectors (1 vector per channel)
uint32_t temp;
while( !feof(wavFile) ) {
    for(uint16_t i = 0; i < numChannels; i++) {
        temp = 0;
        fread(&temp,sizeof(uint8_t),1,wavFile);
        audioData.at(i).push_back(temp); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Your program will also be unable to properly read single-channel WAV files because you read 1-octet data to `uint32_t` and remain some bits uninitialized. Use `uint8_t` to read data having type `uint8_t` in.

Comment: 2-channel 8-bit WAV contain 16-bit blocks because it ls 8-bit * 2-channel.

Comment: @MikeCAT Just confirming, this means 1-channel 8-bit WAV contains 8-bit blocks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure, which typically describes format of WAV audio data, is described in MSDN here: [WAVEFORMATEX structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd390970):

- "sample" for PCM audio is a block of data, which includes all channels
- `nBlockAlign` value is size, in bytes, of such block corresponding to sample
- samples go at specific fixed rate, defined by `nSamplesPerSec` value
- each sample block consists of `nChannels` values, each one of `wBitsPerSample`

That is, two channel file with 8 bits per sample has `nSamplesPerSec` pairs for each second of audio data, each pair includes two 8-bit values for every channel of the two.

([here](http://www.jensign.com/riffparse/) is an example of where this structure exists in the WAV file - though this is a more complicated case with 24-bits/sample, but you should get the idea).