# How to write multiple sound tracks in a wav. file by c++

Tags: c++, wav

I want to use c++ to write waveform samples into a wav. file, but I got confused when I have more than one sound tracks, should I write them all into a wav. file one by one or should I calculate the mixed waveform and sample it, then write it as a single sound track?

Sorry if there is something I misunderstood, I'm not familiar with wav. file structure.

Here is my code:

```
//Creat headers here

const int sample_rate = 44100;
int tri_wave(int fre, int sample_rate){
    //calculation of sample
    return sample;
}

int square_wave(int fre, int sample_rate){
    //calculation of sample
    return sample;
}

int16_t make_wave(int fre, int sample_rate){
    //do something
    return sample;
}

int main(){
    std::ofstream out("test.wav", std::ios::binary);
    out.write(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&wav), sizeof(wav));//write header of wav. file

    int16_t sample_track1 = make_wave(fre1, sample_rate);
    int16_t sample_track2 = make_wave(fre2, sample_rate);
    for (int i = 0; i < fsize; ++i) {
      // write in blocks
      out.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&sample), sizeof(int16_t));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are sourcing many other files from your .bash_profile. Did you check them too?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35825617/can-8-bit-bits-per-sample-pcm-wav-files-contain-more-than-one-channel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing each track into a separate channel or resample all tracks into a single channel really depends on what your expected result is.

- If you want mono audio or if you are otherwise limited to a single channel, resample all tracks into a single channel.
- Otherwise, write each track into its own channel.

If you go for multiple channels, please keep in mind that other software can infer a use for each channel based on a list of [standard speaker channels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surround_sound#Standard_speaker_channels).

Some good sources on the RIFF / WAVE file format i've used myself to read and write wav files:

[http://web.archive.org/web/20160530121622/http://www.blitter.com/~russtopia/MIDI/~jglatt/tech/wave.htm](http://web.archive.org/web/20160530121622/http://www.blitter.com/%7Erusstopia/MIDI/%7Ejglatt/tech/wave.htm)

http://web.archive.org/web/20140821040519/http://www.sonicspot.com/guide/wavefiles.html

The part you are most likely interested in:

> Multi-channel digital audio samples are stored as interlaced wave data
> which simply means that the audio samples of a multi-channel (such as
> stereo and surround) wave file are stored by cycling through the audio
> samples for each channel before advancing to the next sample time.
> This is done so that the audio files can be played or streamed before
> the entire file can be read. This is handy when playing a large file
> from disk (that may not completely fit into memory) or streaming a
> file over the Internet. The values in the diagram below would be
> stored in a Wave file in the order they are listed in the Value column
> (top to bottom).
>
> | Time | Channel | Value |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 0 | 1 (left) | 0x0053 |
> |  | 2 (right) | 0x0024 |
> | 1 | 1 (left) | 0x0057 |
> |  | 2 (right) | 0x0029 |
> | 2 | 1 (left) | 0x0063 |
> |  | 2 (right) | 0x003C |

Please note that your write loop definitely will *not* write your samples as provided in your question:

```
for (int i = 0; i < fsize; ++i) {
  // write in blocks
  out.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&sample), sizeof(int16_t));
}
```

During this loop the address of `sample` remains the same, so each iteration writes the same 2 bytes.

And the way you cast `int16_t` to `char` will produce data with your systems' [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness), but it has to be little endian (least significant byte first). This might not be an issue for your project it just is not portable.
To do this in a portable way, you get each byte your self instead of using the way data is stored in memory.

Writing a single sample to your filestream can be done like this:

```
void write_sample(std::ofstream& out, uint16_t sample)
{
    // little endian (least significant byte first)
    out.put( static_cast<char>(    (sample)&0xFF) ); // first byte
    out.put( static_cast<char>( (sample>>8)&0xFF) ); // second byte
}
```

And an example of how to use it with multiple (4) channels:

```
// Open file for writing
// Write Wave file header (12 bytes)
// Write Format chunk with (26 or more bytes)
// Write Data chunk header (8 bytes)

uint16_t* track_C1 = make_wave( 523, sample_rate, fsize);
uint16_t* track_E1 = make_wave( 660, sample_rate, fsize);
uint16_t* track_G1 = make_wave( 784, sample_rate, fsize);
uint16_t* track_C2 = make_wave(1047, sample_rate, fsize);

for (int i=0; i<fsize; i++) {
    write_sample(out, track_C1[i]);
    write_sample(out, track_E1[i]);
    write_sample(out, track_G1[i]);
    write_sample(out, track_C2[i]);
}

// Close file
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I read that if I have 2 channels I need to write like ```0x13 0x64 0x24 0x34``` where represent for t =0 left, t=0 right, t=1 left, t=1 right (if I'm wrong please correct me), what if I have 4 sound tracks? Should I declear number channel =4 and write them separately?    (assume I have four instruments)

Comment: That is correct for 2 channels. If you have 4 channels, you write: `t=0 channel=0`,`t=0 channel=1`,`t=0 channel=2`,`t=0 channel=3`,`t=1 channel=0`,`t=1 channel=1`,`t=1 channel=2`,`t=1 channel=3`,etc...

Comment: Thank you. And for casting problem between ```int16_t``` and ```char```, how can I avoid such problem? I saw the ofstream::write() requires char* as the input, is there other functions I can use for writing ```int16_t``` or ```int8_t```?

Comment: I've added an example of how to write a sample in a portable way